# compare a value from \newcounter to value from \newcount

Tags: macros, counters

I searched for this topic, but I didn't find anything, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

I've got the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\newcount\testA
\testA=1

\newcounter{testB}
\setcounter{testB}{1}

\ifnum\testA=\testB
TRUE
\else
FALSE
\fi
```

That is not working. It gets an error message. I also tried:

```
\newcount\testA
\testA=1

\newcounter{testB}
\setcounter{testB}{1}

\ifnum\testA=\value{\testB} %edit: solution is \value{testB}
TRUE
\else
FALSE
\fi
```

This works neither and gets an error message "undefined".

The workaround worked:

```
\newcount\testA
\testA=1

\newcounter{testB}
\setcounter{testB}{1}

\newcounter{temp}
\setcounter{temp}{\testA}

\arabic{temp}

\ifnum\temp=\testB
TRUE
\else
FALSE
\fi
```

How can I get this to work without the workaround? Is there a direct way.

Comment: it's `\ifnum\testA=\value{testB}`

Comment: Of course. I supposed, that it is simple like that. Didn't see it though. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of the internal counter is `\c@testB`. And \value will work if you remove the backslash.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\newcount\testA
\testA=1

\newcounter{testB}
\setcounter{testB}{1}

\makeatletter
\ifnum\testA=\c@testB
TRUE
\else
FALSE
\fi
\makeatother


\ifnum\testA=\value{testB}
TRUE
\else
FALSE
\fi
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to use

```
\ifnum\testA=\value{testB}
```